# Creating Multiple Auth Providers in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, lumen

I am trying to create multiple Auth Guards and services for my API. I want specific group to be available to specific users (more like RBAC without sessions).

If a user tries to access a group that has `admin:auth` as middleware its privileges will be checked. If it has `api:auth` then no privilege check.

I can't understand how to do this. I have added the following lines in the **bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'admin' => App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    'api' => App\Http\Middleware\Api::class,
]);
```

And:

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AdminServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(App\Providers\ApiServiceProvider::class);
```

and created the Files **Admin.php** and **APi.php** in **Middleware** folder with the following content (basically same as Authenticate.php with name changes)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * The authentication guard factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And the **AdminServiceProvider** and **ApiServiceProvider** in the **App\Providers** folder with just this in function **boot()**:

```
var_dump($this->app['api']);exit;
```

And this on top:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ApiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
```

But I get the Following Error:

[image: Error]

What am I missing? I have already done `composer dump-autoload`, no difference.

Regards

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution ? I got the same error :(

Comment: @Jicao: I think I changed my method. I added a middleware to a parent group then added another to another group. I made my URL tree to follow the Middleware logic.

Comment: @echo_salik, could you post your solution? I would like to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @bou2you I used groups, a parent group with one middleware and a child group with other. It's not a programmatic solution, more like a work around, I'll post it as an answer later today.

Comment: @echo_salik thx. yes, if you could post your solution so I can see how you got it to work, it would really help me out. :)

Comment: @bou2you I have posted the answer, sorry it took me a little while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what I ended up using is more like a work around, but I think this might be how it is supposed to be used.

So what I did was that I created two groups (a parent and a child) with the middlewares I needed as follows:

```
$app->group(["middleware" => "middleware1"], function() use ($app){
  $app->group(["middleware" => "middleware1"], function() use ($app){
    $app->post("/signin", "AppController@signin");
  }
}
```

This way, the `signin` route is reached after going through 2 middlewares.

Regards